# UnAuthorized error with access token generated from Outlook WebAddin

Tags: exchangewebservices, outlook-addin, office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am trying to use access token generated in Outlook Addin to download mail attachments, it is throwing an unauthorized error(401). Looks AccessToken is not valid. Using the accessToken within 5 min after generation in the add-in to make sure to avoid expired code.

Followed steps suggested in [Office documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/get-attachments-of-an-outlook-item) and created the C# code. My code gist is available [here](https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/6b0ba1db1599500a94451958b4f52d79) : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/6b0ba1db1599500a94451958b4f52d79

My add-in manifest is available [here](https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/5ef93e3df80f304826742bb81a0b4421#file-addin-manifest-xml-L64) which asks [ReadWriteMailbox](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions#restricted-permission) permission : https://gist.github.com/rajeevprasanna/5ef93e3df80f304826742bb81a0b4421#file-addin-manifest-xml-L64

I am experimenting on Office365 Outlook WebClient but I have to work on a uniform solution which works on all outlook instances and office365 and Exchange versions.

Code for extracting access token as suggested [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.5/office.context.mailbox#getcallbacktokenasyncoptions-callback) :

```
let cb = (asyncResult) => {
    console.log('asyncResult => '+ R.toString(asyncResult));
};

var options = {
        isRest: true,
        asyncContext: { message: 'Hello World!' }
    };
Office.context.mailbox.getCallbackTokenAsync(options, cb);
```

Using the value filed of the callback response as accessToken while making API call. 
sample getCallbackTokenAsync response :

```
{
    "asyncContext": {
        "message": "Hello World!"
    },
    "status": "succeeded",
    "value": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImthME5Hb19aNUkwRms1MXpKblZjT2tHbzFvbyJ9.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.c3sknGGbw1Jrip9Ke1AcLyRL-6VnWSSWTGrwmeo6Z7xwBfKD3ppNkSqb4cVZIzuV-8udQps2abQ9scPMn0DNRbFRUNlBfkhHUqR2_JHrMcMptL6ZqF-a7_-gOMcBSgNdUCk5mhGDJs9qiEiM47thv5HZC97k-aYZ-iyU8N-8SgMNDc8vjBdS2nPSKp6FgQfezmjxADT-mbflxNUIwUDfOAys2l8v_Qw30t3LDca2AMmHyK3GbEaXejdO4muzC-ZrRMUVThIfFsMs0x67E2aY--lxSwDmrfcEnXODW0_J72RtFNDV5wjxf1QH6-xfP0A34qbUlmVnjjiCeYCeCCtNEg"
}
```

After doing some trails and comparing with an example [project](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Outlook-Add-in-JavaScript-GetAttachments), i found the error seems to be with permission type **ReadWriteMailbox**. I am able to fetch attachments if query is done with permission type **ReadItem** or **ReadWriteItem**

Comment: Which client are you trying this from - Outlook Desktop, Web or Mac? Is your exchange backend on Office365 or is it On-Prem?

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT updated the question with details you asked.

Comment: can you run the sample code at this link to see if succeeds in your add-in? Please use an e-mail that contains a single attachment. The attachment should be a plain text file attachment. Here's the link : https://gist.github.com/exextoc/472f3c261d654e0eeacd10cad7e0c658

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT,  This solution is working. but it will not support in old outlook version where isRest is not supported. how to handle those cases?

Comment: For clients that do not support isRest, we recommend using EWS instead to retrieve attachments.In your call to getcallbacktokenasync do not pass in isRest(it would default to false) and give you a token you can use against EWS.